# Which way to reserve memory for a string?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, c-preprocessor

I have created a macro to make reserve memory for my strings in **C**. It looks like this:

```
#define newString(size) (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) + size)
```

So is there any reason I shouldn't use this macro in my own personal projects? I know I shouldn't do this in production code because it would require everyone to have that header file and everyone to know that `newString` was a macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size+1))` would be more appropriate (the +1 is to account for the NULL at the end of string, if applicable).

If one is copying a string, [strlen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) doesn't account for the NULL terminating the string hence an additional memory `char` is required.

Comment: Instead of `size+1`, use `size + sizeof('\0')` which may be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure it's a good idea to use the preprocessor to save yourself some typing. (That road is dark and scary.) It won't be long before you'll want to add something to your macro, and you'll start running into problems that will be way hard to debug.

If you're rolling your own memory management, then use a real function and provide a complimentary "delete" function.

If you're worried about performance, your compiler is smart enough to inline little functions for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the allocation was successful.

```
char* ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size); //Not '+' size!!
if (ptr == 0) //or NULL if defined
{
    //cannot allocate
}
```

But there is no problem in using a macro

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that `sizeof(char)` is defined to always be 1. So you should write instead:

```
malloc(size)
```

and it will be shorter to write this than `newString(size)`. Also, `malloc` returns a `void *` which you don't need to cast in C.

The other reason is so you don't write a `+` when you mean `*`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using sizeof(char). We all know it is 1, and that it is unlikely to change, but there isn't any drawback to having extra information. It isn't like he will need to type this over and over again. He is defining the macro for that reason.

Comment: To add to what **@A. Levy** said, `char` is also more readable then having a magic number lying around.

Comment: But `sizeof(char) == 1` will *never* change, and there is a drawback: it makes the code more verbose and cluttered. I would immediately become suspicious of any code I saw using `sizeof(char)` as to me that is an indication that the author does not know C that well.

Comment: One reason to specify sizeof is that your code may use 16-bit Unicode characters in addition to 8-bit ASCII ones.

Comment: Of course it will change.  When you move to Unicode and Search+Replace "char" to "wchar_t".

Comment: @nobugz: Such a significant change requires a bit more than some simple Search+Replaces. Better use p=malloc(sizeof(*p)*size); in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your macro is equivalent to

```
malloc(size + 1)
```

as in C you don't need to cast the result of `malloc` and `sizeof(char)` equals `1` by definition. So it doesn't really save you much typing. I would recommend against it, even in your personal projects, as I don't see any benefit to it.